# Retrieve from Firestore just the UserID in the array Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I have a stream Builder in firestore which display a list of user.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('Users').where('recentUser',arrayContainsAny: ['userId'])
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Center(
              child: CupertinoActivityIndicator()
            );
          }
          final data = snapshot.data!.docs;
```

in the Firestore collection I have a document which have userId Field and an array of user ID.

I am trying to retrieve the list of user and for a specific user I want to retrieve just the user that the id is in the array `recentUser`
As per above example I have tried to user `.where('recentUser',arrayContainsAny: ['userId'])`
but unsuccesfully...
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

try replacing **['userId']** with **[userId]** or **['$userId']** depending on type

Comment: Can you expand on when one would be needed over the other? That will help readers less familiar with this syntax.

Comment: The one OP used is just a hardcoded string 'userId' which shouldn't be used. ['$userId'] is used when the local userId type is an integer but on the database is a String. [userId] is used when the local userId type is the same as the type on the database.